# Nginx redirect to reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am having difficulty with setting up nginx reverse proxy, few backgrounds of my case :
Server is AWS EC2 ubuntu
Nginx version is 1.18.0
My app language is PHP with Laravel Framework 8.1

My aim is to setup my.domain.com/ to redirect to my.domain.com/app1, and then my.domain.com/app1 will open app1, I will do the same for app2, app3 etc.

I tried setting up reverse proxy, and for testing, I have successfully use reverse proxy for
location / to open app1 in port 8001.
Here is my nginx config in sites-available for proxy :

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name my.domain.com;
        return 301 https://my.domain.com$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 443;


        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

        charset utf-8;


        server_name my.domain.com;

        add_header 'Content-Security-Policy' 'upgrade-insecure-requests';

        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;

                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        }

        # Remove trailing slash to please routing system.
        if (!-d $request_filename) {
            rewrite     ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
        }

}
```

and here is my nginx config for the app in port 8001 :

```
server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:8001;

        root /var/www/app1/public;


        index index.php;
        port_in_redirect off;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
                deny all;
        }

}
```

From this point, I thought I only need to redirect location / to /app1, and reverse proxy location /app1 to port 8001, here is the part in the first config I changed :

```
        location / {
                return 301 /app1;
        }
        add_header 'Content-Security-Policy' 'upgrade-insecure-requests';

#       location / {
        location /app1 {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;

                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        }
```

but this resulted in nginx trying to access application route "/app1" in the application itself, which I tested by making the route app1 in the web.php.
what is wrong / lacking in my config ? any insight for my case is greatly appreciated !
Thank you.